# Mysql transactions and RabbitMq

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, rabbitmq

I have to do a save in the mysql db, and then send an event over rabbitmq to my clients.

Now when pushing to RMq, if it fails for whatever reason, i need to rollback the save. It should be all or nothing, there cannot be data in the db for which events have not gone out.

So essentially,

```
Begin Transaction
Save to db
Push to queue
If exception rollback else commit
End transaction
```

Another approach

Now i can do the save operation only in the transaction. And then after that have some way of retrying the queuing if it fails, but that becomes overly complex.

Are there any best practices around this? Any suggestions regarding which approach to follow.

PS: the events over rmq contain ids for which some data has changed. The clients are expected to do a http get for the changed ids to perform their actions.

Answer (score 0):

Well you pretty much doing everything right. RabbitMQ guys published a good article about semaphore queues: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/02/19/distributed-semaphores-with-rabbitmq/

I would consider this to be a "best practice", since it is written by the people who somehow involved in developing the RabbitMQ.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, but i do not understand how this solves the problem of atomicity, can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your main concern is whether you published the message to exchange successfully. You can use [Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) in RabbitMQ to be sure that your message is accepted by the queue.

Depending on how did you design the updates in your DB and how much time difference is tolerated from DB update to your clients getting the ID few things come to mind:

1. You can add a new field in a DB that you can use as a flag to check if the message for specific update is sent to the RabbitMQ. When you do the update you set the flag to 0, try to publish the message to the exchange and if it is successful you update the flag to 1. This can be complicated if you need to use the old values until the message to the clients has been sent and will require you to go through the database in some intervals and try to send the message to RabbitMQ again for all rows that don't have a flag set to 1.
2. Publish the message to RabbitMQ and if you get the confirm you then commit the DB update. If the commit for any reason fails your clients will do the update but get the old values which usually won't be problematic, but it really depends on your application. This is probably the better/easier way especially since there is no reason to expect anything to fail constantly. You should also consider to add some kind of short delay on the client side from the time it receives the ID for update and actually doing the update (to give some time for DB update).

Answer (score 0):

In such heterogeneous environment you can use [Two Phase Commits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol). You add "dirty " record to db, publish message, then edit record to mark it "clean" and ready.

Also when you deal with messaging middleware you have to be ready that some messages may be potentially lost or their consumer fail to process it in full, so maybe some feedback from consumer may be required, say you publish message and when consumer receive it, then it will add record to db.